# How do they make multiple columns to a single line with spaces between?

Tags: sublimetext3

https://www.sublimetext.com/ on "video" 2/6 how do they make multiple columns to a single line with spaces between?

Thanks

Comment: Ctrl-J joins multiple lines together. Really, if you want to figure out how Sublime works, explore the menus and [read the docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

On Sublime, you can put every selected line on a unique line by pressing Ctrl+J.

Other possibility:

When you are at the end of a line and press "Delete" it erase the end of line.
Indeed, "Delete", unlike "Backspace" erase the character on the right of the cursor, not on the left

Example:

```
qqqqq
aaaaa
```

If you put the cursor at the end of qqqqq and press "Delete", you obtain:

```
qqqqqaaaaa
```

Now in subime, with multiple cursor, you do the same thing it will erase every cursor's right character.

To have multiple cursor, press Alt+Shift and use the up or down array on your keyboard. You can also your the middle button of your mouse to create multiple cursors.

Once your cursors create, press "End" key on your keyboard to place all the cursors at the end of their line. Thus, you can press "Delete". Your column will become a line. Then, feel free to add spaces, comas or other punctuations.